# Referencing separate workbook cell - can it NOT default to absolute reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When entering a formula in Workbook 1, Sheet1, that references Workbook2, Sheet1, Excel *automatically* creates an Absolute Reference:

[image]

I rarely need this to be absolute column and cell reference. So normally, I just hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and remove the `$`.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can change, so Excel defaults to a "regular" reference, i.e.

```
=[Book4]Sheet1!C4
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't. A triple-tap on F4 is the quickest workaround.

[image]

Comment: Oh, yeah good call with `F2`. I'm still looking around for some way to change the default behavior, but I think this is the best solution.

Comment: `F4` changes the reference. `F2` does something else, depending on where you are.

Comment: (D'oh, that was a typo I meant to say `F4`)